# Equality for .NET PropertyInfos

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, propertyinfo

I have some code that compares 2 PropertyInfos with Equals(). While this normally seems to work, I have run into a strange situation where two reflected property info objects for the same underlying property are not equal:

```
PropertyInfo prop1, prop2; // both are public and not static
Console.WriteLine(prop1 == prop2); // false ???
Console.WriteLine(Equals(prop1, prop2)); // false ???
Console.WriteLine(prop1.DeclaringType == prop2.DeclaringType); // true
Console.WriteLine(prop1.ReturnType == prop2.ReturnType); // true
Console.WriteLine(prop1.Name == prop2.Name); // true
Console.WriteLine(prop1.DeclaringType.GetProperties().Contains(prop1)); // true
Console.WriteLine(prop2.DeclaringType.GetProperties().Contains(prop2)); // false ???
```

It looks like PropertyInfo does not actually implement Equals(), but I thought that .NET caches reflected members so that the same instance is always returned. You certainly see a.GetType() == b.GetType() all the time. Is this not the case for PropertyInfos?

Some other notes:
-This weirdness happened when running an NUnit test in .NET 4, VS2012, x86 build target
-This doesn't even happen for all properties we compare this way, but it fails consistently on one property.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

EDIT: in case anyone is interested, here is the EqualityComparison function I wrote to compare MemberInfos:

```
public class MemberEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<MemberInfo> {
    public override bool Equals(MemberInfo @this, MemberInfo that) {
        if (@this == that) { return true; }
        if (@this == null || that == null) { return false; }

                        // handles everything except for generics
                    if (@this.MetadataToken != that.MetadataToken
                        || !Equals(@this.Module, that.Module)
                        || this.Equals(@this.DeclaringType, that.DeclaringType))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    bool areEqual;
                    switch (@this.MemberType)
                    {
                        // constructors and methods can be generic independent of their types,
                        // so they are equal if they're generic arguments are equal
                        case MemberTypes.Constructor:
                        case MemberTypes.Method:
                            var thisMethod = @this as MethodBase;
                            var thatMethod = that as MethodBase;
                                                areEqual = thisMethod.GetGenericArguments().SequenceEqual(thatMethod.GetGenericArguments(), 
this);
                            break;
                        // properties, events, and fields cannot be generic independent of their types,
                        // so if we've reached this point without bailing out we just return true.
                        case MemberTypes.Property:
                        case MemberTypes.Event:
                        case MemberTypes.Field:
                            areEqual = true;
                            break;
                        // the system guarantees reference equality for types, so if we've reached this point
                        // without returning true the two are not equal
                        case MemberTypes.TypeInfo:
                        case MemberTypes.NestedType:
                            areEqual = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new NotImplementedException(@this.MemberType.ToString());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(MemberInfo memberInfo) {
        if (memberInfo == null) { return 0; }

    var hash = @this.MetadataToken 
        ^ @this.Module.GetHashCode() 
        ^ this.GetHashCode(@this.DeclaringType);
    return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen the decompiled code?

Comment: @smartcaveman, did you intend to return false whenever the declaring types are equal? I think there should be a "not" in there. Also, the last few lines of your Equals method seem to be cut off, as there's no return statement or closing brace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing they have a different `ReflectedType`. For example, inheritance:

```
class A {
   public int Foo {get;set;}
}
class B : A {}
```

now look at `typeof(A).GetProperty("Foo")` and `typeof(B).GetProperty("Foo")`.

Answer (score 16):

Object identity is only promised for the Type class, not for the other reflection classes.  A *possibly* sound way to compare for equality is to check that the properties have the same metadata token and came from the same module.  So try this:

```
bool equal = prop1.MetadataToken == prop2.MetadataToken &&
             prop1.Module.Equals(prop2.Module);
```

Which makes sense as long as ecma 335 applies.  I could not test this against your code since you didn't post it.  So just try it.

Comment: This seems to work, except for properties of generic types (unless you want List<int>.Count == List<string>.Count).

Comment: @ChaseMedallion, How about adding a conjunction with `prop1.DeclaringType == prop2.DeclaringType` as well?  Seems like that would cover that case

Comment: @smartcaveman: DeclaringType handles property generics well, since properties themselves cannot be generic (just the declaring type). However, to extend this method to all members you need to do some additional checking to handle generic methods. See my posted code (in the question) for a (seemingly) complete set of checks for arbitrary members. You'll notice the DeclaringType check towards the top.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion - I see.  I didn't realize you were the OP when I commented.  FYI, if you want `prop2.DeclaringType.GetProperties().Contains(prop2)` to use your `MemberEqualityComparer` and return true, you should check out [Undefault.NET](https://github.com/smartcaveman/undefault) (disclaimer: I made it)

Comment: And I even have the same problem with 2 System.RuntimeTypes (they're not MemberInfos). They have the exact same Module and same GUID - same everything. But Equals returns false.

Comment: I found the answer. The problem is in System.RuntimeType. System.RuntimeType is overriding the Equals method to do just an object == check (which checks equality by reference). Very bad. Probably the cause of a lot of bugs in people's programs.