# Using PropertyInfo as key

Tags: c#, reflection

I am creating app where I need to cache my custom attribute, so I was thinking about best approach and decided to use ConcurrentDictionary as my "cache". My question is if I can use PropertyInfo, or MethodInfo as keys? Are they unique for each method and are they same for each comparison?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out? `PropertyInfo` and `MethodInfo` seem like very inefficient keys if you need quick lookups, but I'm sure you could make it work.

Comment: What have you tried? Dictionary keys will be hashed using `GetHashCode()`. Hashes are consistent but not necessarily unique. Perhaps you'd better use a fully qualified name as key (assembly-namespace-type-member).

Comment: @DanWilson I know that reflection is quite pricey, but I already got them as passing parameters into method which I am editing, so I thought that this is simplier solution than creating for each method an argument unqie strign key

Comment: @CodeCaster from my tests it seems that my solution should work, but I still have doubts if is this realy "safe" solution.

Comment: Relying on this is iffy. Because `PropertyInfo` and `MethodInfo` do not override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, you're getting the default reference equality from `Object`. Although reflection metadata caching (and other internals) means that you *should* get back the same instance every time you get them in one particular way, there is not technically a guarantee that you will. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13615927/4137916) for more subtle ways this can go wrong (and an alternate approach that may be safer).

Comment: I doubt anyone here could say with certainty whether you will have key conflicts at some point.